# Вопрос по замыканию js

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Почему данный код выдает в консоль 0? Ведь я возвращаю counts, увеличенный на единицу

```js
const counter = (counts) => {
  return counts++;
};
const makerCounter = (counter) => {
  let counts = 0;
  return () => counter(counts);
};

const getCounter = makerCounter(counter);

console.log(getCounter());
console.log(getCounter());
```

Comment: Может быть это потому, что `++` срабатывает после `return`. Попробуйте `return ++counts;` Ничего не слыхали о постфиксных и префиксных инкрементах?

Comment: А еще вы не используете `let counts` нигде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы возвращаете единицу, а потом ее увеличиваете на 1. В даном случае надо использовать преинкримент, чтобы сначала увеличить, а потом вернуть.

И `let counts = 0;` тоже нигде не используете, не ясно зачем он там.

```js
const counter = (counts = 0) => {
  return ++counts;
};
const makerCounter = (counter) => {
  return (counts) => counter(counts);
};

const getCounter = makerCounter(counter);

console.log(getCounter(2));
console.log(getCounter());
```

Comment: я хотел написать счетчик через замыкание, но для этого вынести саму функцию подсчета